# Does HTML5 change anything if I don't use video or audio?

Tags: html

I keep hearing all about HTML5 and how great it is, but if I don't really care about audio and video, is there anything it really changes for me? I've read up on the new tags it supports and they just don't seem to be all that revolutionary beyond its video and audio capabilities.

Comment: -1 - I think about 5 minutes on Google should be able to answer this one for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly copy-pasted from wikipedia:

- The canvas element for immediate mode 2D drawing.
- Timed media playback (possibly not interesting for you)
- Offline storage database (offline web applications). See Web Storage[21]
- Document editing (via DOM API and user interface)
- Drag-and-drop
- Cross-document messaging
- Browser history management
- MIME type and protocol handler registration.
- Microdata
- Browser-based SQL databases
- Oh, and WebSockets to replace AJAX and Comet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#New_APIs

Answer (score 2):

- DOM storage
- Canvas
- Drag'n'drop
- Semantic microformats support

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest deals about HTML5 which is under reported is that HTML4 never defined error handing, but this is well defined in HTML5. All browser vendors are building HTML5 parsers that conform to this spec. While this is not sexy, the end result will be that browsers will become more interoperable with each other (especially in cases where the author makes an error). In the long run this should mean you'll spend less time trying to get all browsers to work correctly, and users will benefit from less broken sites in their browser of choice.

HTML5 also allows you to make more application quality sites, using many of the technologies mentioned in the other answers. Opera Dragonfly (the project I'm involved with) is a complex web app which doesn't use audio or video but takes advantage of a large number of HTML5 technologies. We use AppCache to make sure it still works when you are offline, Web Storage to save user preferences and history (we can store a lot more information than cookies allowed) and will likely use Web Workers to allow the app to use more than one process at once (will speed up performance on mult-core machines).

If you are doing anything with graphics then the Canvas API gives you a lot of drawing options, while SVG (an open vector format) can be used within your HTML pages now. Previously pages had to be served as XML for SVG to be included inside them.